# How do I permanently remove ClickOnce Security from VS C# project

Tags: c#, publish

I have an application that I would like to publish on disk.

I am able to do this, but each time I publish the ClickOnce security tickbox get checked.

This causes my app problems. How can I publish WITHOUT ClickOnce security getting switched on?